# Python Name Abreviation finding

Tags: python, maya

I get info that reads like this

```
xy123, xy0123, xyz_123, and xy01
```

`XYZ` being different letters and `123` being different numbers. For example `QWA_0230`. I get letters and numbers any amount seperated by a `_` sometimes.

I'm interested in a line of code that will find the letters at the beginning no matter if there is a `_` or not with as many letters as it comes in with. Right now I can find it if there is a `_`. But not sure what to do if there is not one.

```
name="QWA_0230"
begName=name.split("_")[0]
#begName=QWA

#name2="QW0210"
#want the same code to work with this kind of name
```

I think I would need like an if statement to find if there is an `_` if true run what I got. If false run something else that can decipher when letters stop and numbers start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [itertools.takewhile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile), taking characters up to the first non alpha character.

```
from itertools import takewhile
name = "QWA_0230"

beg_name = "".join(takewhile(str.isalpha,name))
print(beg_name)
QWA


name2 = "QW0210"

beg_name = "".join(takewhile(str.isalpha,name2))
print(beg_name)
QW
```

For the digits, you can use `itertools.dropwhile`:

```
name2="QW0210"

print("".join(dropwhile(lambda x: not x.isdigit(),name2)))
```

Or  you can use `isalpha` or `isdigit` in a loop:

```
print("".join(x for x in name if x.isalpha()))

print("".join(x for x in name if x.isdigit())
```

If speed is an issue this will beat just abut any other option:

```
a,b = name.translate(None,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXWY_"),name.translate(None,"1234567890_")

In [8]: %%timeit
res = expr.search("QWA_0230").groups()
a,b = res[0],res[-1]
   ...: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 830 ns per loop

In [9]: timeit a,b = name.translate(None,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXWY_"),name.translate(None,"1234567890_")

1000000 loops, best of 3: 510 ns per loop

In [17]: a,b = name.translate(None,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXWY_"),name.translate(None,"1234567890_")
In [18]: a
Out[18]: '0230'    
In [19]: b
Out[19]: 'QWA
```

Comment: Thanks this seams to work pretty well I'll do some further tests.

Comment: @cjaxx, no prob,  it will always work for letters `A-Z`

Comment: How would I get the numbers in a separate variable. @padraic-cunningham

Comment: @cjaxx, added a few options

Comment: @cjaxx if people's answers were helpful to you, be sure to give them a +1 for their effort to help you

Comment: @JonClements ugh. Time to get some sleep!

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with a regular expression:

```
import re
expr = re.compile("([a-z]+)(_?)([0-9]+)", re.I)  # case insensitive
expr.search("QWA_0230").groups()
#  ('QWA', '_', '0230')

expr.search("xy123").groups()
#  ('xy', None, '123')
```

if there is data that has neither numbers nor letters you need to check for the search coming back as none:

```
result = expr.search("xy123")
if not result: 
   return (None,None,None)
return result.groups()
```

the letters will always be groups[0] and the numbers will be groups[-1]

Comment: +1 I am pretty sure, that regular expressions are the way to go. Most of the times, they are faster than other solutions.

Comment: @Juergen, not faster than str.translate

Comment: @Padraic: I posted my comment, before you came about with str.translate. That is true, that in this specific case translate is probably the fastest solution. When you have a look on my statement, I formulated my statement very carefully. You can't use translate in many situations, where regular expressions are applicable.